# Dynamic Range Used for Intersect Target

Tags: dynamic, range, intersect

I am working on a spreadsheet that utilizes user input to fill out a table. This data is entered into a table with numerous columns required. I have a command button that creates a new row and inserts all the data validation necessary for a new line item (below is an example.)

[image: Spreadsheet the user sees]

My problem revolves on a specific a column (blue circle) where other cells rely on based on a "yes" or "no" string. If the column has a "yes", the adjacent cells do something. If the column has a "no", the adjacent cells do something different.

As this table grows in rows, my column range I am focused on will change dynamically. I want the VBA code to run if the worksheet experiences a change event in that dynamic range  utilizing the "Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) sub.

Right now, I am defining that dynamic range in my commandbutton_click sub because everytime i click the button, a new row is added thus I need the spreadsheet to be aware that my range has changed (see my code below).

```
    Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim LastRowEntry As Long
    Dim DeviceNo As Integer
    'Dim RTUTable As Range

    'Determine the last entry row & Copy
    LastRowEntry = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    DeviceNo = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
    Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).EntireRow.Copy
    'Once the last row is determined, go to the next row to paste
    Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValidation
    'Incase the above cell has Conditional Formatting, we set the color back to "white"
    Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.Value = DeviceNo + 1

    With RTUTable
    RTUTable = Sheet1.Range(("G7"), Sheet1.Cells(LastRowEntry + 1, "G"))
    End With

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Then, in a different sub I enter code that will "check" to see if that dynamic range has had a change in value with a "yes" or "no" answer. This is where I enter my defined dynamic range (see my code below).

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False

'This code checks to see if the Device is polled by RTU
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range(RTUTable)) Is Nothing Then

            If ActiveCell.Value = "NO" Then
               "DO SOMETHING"
            Else
              "DO SOMETHING"
            End If
    End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Can someone help me out on the error message "Type mismatch" I am receiving? Am I entering the dynamic range correctly into the intersect code?

Thank you

****Update - More information for Clarification*****

I have added some information in the array I am evaluating. Below is a snapshot of my spreadsheet.

[image: Info entered into the spreadsheet]

When I go into the Debug mode, I am viewing my "Locals table" and see I am successfully capturing my information in an array.

[image: Local Values in the VBA code]

I need to run the intersect command with this array

Comment: Avoid posting images of your code because it makes it impossible to copy and paste for someone to test and reduces the chances that people will work with it. Instead, copy the code and paste it here so that it's easier for someone who wishes to assist to help you.

Comment: Thank you Fabulous for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved. Below is the code I used to determine the dynamic range and then the code evaluates that range for a change.

```
Dim dyString As String
Dim dyRange As Range
Dim LastRowEntry_1 As Integer
Dim i As Integer

LastRowEntry_1 = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(-2, 0).row + 1

dyString = "G8:G" & LastRowEntry_1
Set dyRange = Range(dyString)

If Not Intersect(Target, dyRange) Is Nothing Then
    For i = 1 To 6
        If ActiveCell.Value = "NO" Then
            Target.Offset(0, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 23
            Target.Offset(0, i).Font.Color = vbWhite
            Target.Offset(0, i).Value = "N/A"
            Target.Offset(0, i).Locked = True
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Value = "YES" And ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Value = "N/A" Then
            Target.Offset(0, i).Value = ""
            Target.Offset(0, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
            Target.Offset(0, i).Font.Color = vbBlack
            Target.Offset(0, i).Locked = False
```

To summarize:

- No matter what, my dynamic range will always begin at cell "G8"
- After that, the range will change dynamically. Either grows or shortens depending on 
  the info. So my "LastRowEntry_1" determines where that last cell entry is. (Note: I 
  had to offset it because of some footer information on my spreadsheet)
- I created a string where I could combine the range of the fixed cell to the dynamic 
  cell.
- Then I set that string as a range.
- Then based if the target range was intersected or not, I run a "For" loop to perform 
  my conditional formatting.